# C#, Visual Studio 2010, PowerPoint. Best practice?

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I've been googling methods for interacting with PowerPoint via C# and have had a play with Interop and VSOT (I think - is this a wrapper around Interop).

Does anyone have any tips or pointers on best practice ? I seem to find several different methods for dealing PowerPoint files. I essentially need to replace text, apply styles and update charts and tables. I'm not creating them - everything will be done from template files.

Comment: Maybe the macros could help you. But this has nothing to do with c#

Comment: Most of what you describe could be done via VBA inside powerpoint, but .NET and Interop is probably going to be more robust and flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option, especially if you are working with newer extensions (pptx, xlsx, etc) is OOXML.

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236.aspx) and samples on working with powerpoint [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee358825.aspx)

Comment: Yeah that looks really good, although I suspect it would take too long to get up to speed with the timescales I'm working with. Definitely something to park and look at again in more depth.

Answer (score 0):

> replace text, apply styles and update charts and tables.

I think [**VBA**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814734.aspx) is the simplest way to do that. But if your needs, in future go past these, into more advanced territory, you'll have no choice but to switch to a different approach. **VBA** is limited in many ways.

Comment: Cheers - I think you're right but I'll stick to C# and Interop for the time being. Not a big fan of VBA.